# why is the Java constant_pool memort allocation defined as having size constant_pool_count-1

Tags: java, class, jvm, .class-file

The java class definition ([docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html)) looks like:

```
ClassFile {
    u4             magic;
    u2             minor_version;
    u2             major_version;
    u2             constant_pool_count;
    cp_info        constant_pool[constant_pool_count-1];
    u2             access_flags;
    u2             this_class;
    u2             super_class;
    u2             interfaces_count;
    u2             interfaces[interfaces_count];
    u2             fields_count;
    field_info     fields[fields_count];
    u2             methods_count;
    method_info    methods[methods_count];
    u2             attributes_count;
    attribute_info attributes[attributes_count];
}
```

But why is the constant_pool calculated as constant_pool_count-1? Why is it decreased by 1? I would expect it to be constant_pool[constant_pool_count] NOT constant_pool[constant_pool_count-1].

Answer (score 1):

Because according to the docu you posted:

> The value of the constant_pool_count item is equal to the number of entries in the constant_pool table plus one

Therefore `constant_pool[constant_pool_count]` would result in an invalid index.

As to the reason behind the reason - I can only guess here. Presumably it's due to the choice of indexing beginning with `1` rather than `0`.

Comment: thanks for the reply @Koenigsberg. But if you look at the other arrays it is the size of the count. For example interfaces[interfaces_count]. Why would the constant_pool_count be larger by one then necessary?

Comment: I think I might know. I have done a bit more looking up. Part of the constant pool is the count of the constant pool. Because the constant pool has the value, constant_pool_count - 1 is the number of remaining values in the constant pool. The constant_pool[constant_pool_count-1 ] is optimization.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, constant_pool is indexed from 1 instead of 0, which is a bit against common sense, But this is for the meaning of "no reference to any constant value item" for data pointing to a constant pool index value in a particular case, which can be expressed with an index value of 0